# How to move up SwiftUI `ScrollView` content when keyboard appears?

Tags: swiftui

I'm having a chat view with messages. When message composer gets a focus and keyboard is appeared the height of `ScrollView` decreases. Now I want all messages to move up a little so users can see the same bottom message she saw before. Is there anyway to achieve this with a pure SwiftUI?

```
ScrollViewReader { scrollReader in
    ScrollView {
        LazyVStack(spacing: 24) {
            ForEach(messages, id: \.id) {
                MessageContainer(message: $0)
                    .id($0.id)
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `scrollReader.scrollTo()` to scroll to the last message?

Comment: Yes, it works if a user was at the last message. But if she scrolled somewhere else before keyboard has appeared it's no use :(

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @Vignesh hello, yes i did using an observer to monitor the keyboard show event and adding a padding of the same height as the keyboard when it shows.

Comment: for me the use case is different https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78113615/swiftui-scrollview-content-movement-with-keyboard/78115708?noredirect=1#comment137725680_78115708

can you please check this once

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that uses `ScrollViewReader` to scroll to the tapped message for answering it:

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let messages = Message.dummyData
    @State private var tappedMessage: Message?
    @State private var newMessage = ""
    @FocusState private var focus: Bool

    var body: some View {
        
        ScrollViewReader { scrollReader in
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
                    ForEach(messages, id: \.id) { message in
                        MessageContainer(message: message)
                            .id(message.id)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                tappedMessage = message
                                focus = true
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            }
            if let tappedMessage {
                VStack {
                    TextEditor(text: $newMessage)
                        .frame(height: 80)
                        .padding()
                        .background(
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                                .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                        )
                        .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                        .focused($focus)
                    
                    Button("Send") { self.tappedMessage = nil }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.5) {
                        withAnimation {
                            scrollReader.scrollTo(tappedMessage.id)
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, unfortunately it won't work in my case. I need to move content up on the height of the keyboard (change offset) like Telegram does when keyboard is appeared

Comment: I've been looking for this exact solution for SwiftUI for a long time. Thank so much. Time to hit the blunt. I love you. Fr

Answer (score 0):

Then just try it with `.offset`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let messages = Message.dummyData
    @State private var showNewMessage = false
    @State private var newMessage = ""
    @FocusState private var focus: Bool

    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 24) {
                    ForEach(messages, id: \.id) { message in
                        MessageContainer(message: message)
                            .offset(y: showNewMessage ? -300 : 0)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 16)
            }
            
            
            if showNewMessage == false {
                Button("New Message") {
                    withAnimation {
                        showNewMessage = true
                        focus = true
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Button("Send") {
                        showNewMessage = false
                }
                
                TextEditor(text: $newMessage)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                    .padding()
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                            .stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 1)
                    )
                    .padding(.horizontal, 16)
                    .focused($focus)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I add offset to the message all messages move up, but if you scroll to the top, you can't scroll to the most top message

Comment: you should activate the offset only as long as your textfield input is focused.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case there's a possibility that keyboard will be always appeared and user still can scroll to the top like in Telegram of Facebook messenger :(

Answer (score 0):

It happens because setting offset does not affect on views size.

You can add Spacer view with height equal to keyboard height and all views moved with changing self size.

I'm using [KeyboardGuardian](https://github.com/TimmyWaters/TinderSwipeTest/blob/master/TinderSwipeTest/KeyboardGuardian.swift) for find keyboard offset and use it like that:

```
VStack {
  // ... LazyVStack, ChatControls, etc...
  Spacer()
    .frame(height: -kGuardian.slide)
    .savePosition(in: $kGuardian.rects[0])
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.keyboard, edges: .bottom)
.onAppear() {
  kGuardian.addObserver()
}
.onDisappear() {
  kGuardian.removeObserver()
}
```